# How to measure a GPU Context Switch from Compute to Rendering Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl, compute-shader

In OpenGL, I dispatch compute shader to calculate new vertex positions in a given object model based on equation of motion. Then I render these new vertex positions via a vertex/fragment rendering shader program. My understanding is that every time I dispatch a compute shader, it initiates a GPU device context switch that takes finite amount of time.

Can someone please share how to measure the context switch between compute shader and rendering shader in OpenGL. I am assuming that it is very small amount of time, but I have need to measure it. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specifically measure the context switch time. You can only measure the time between particular OpenGL commands (through timer queries), and there is no OpenGL command to perform a context switch. It is a by-product of the actual OpenGL commands you send.

The closest you can get is something like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(emptyVAO);
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD); //Do the absolute minimal rendering.
glBindProgramPipeline(minimalComputeTask); //Compute shader that does nothing, using no resources and writing no values.
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1); //Done before the timer query, to force a switch to compute contexts.
glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED​, queryObject);
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);
glBindProgramPipeline(minimalRenderShaders); //VS does nothing and takes no inputs; no FS at all, since we're discarding.
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
glEndQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED);
glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

Then you extract the query and read the time. But even this will include the time spent actually executing the compute and rendering operations. And in your case, your time should probably include a `glMemoryBarrier` that would allow the rendering operation to read what the compute shader wrote.

Answer (score 0):

[Timer queries](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries) sound like they ought to work, assuming your GL implementation [meaningfully supports them](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Query_precision):

> Timer queries are the collective name for the query types GL_TIMESTAMP and GL_TIME_ELAPSED. **These are used for measuring the GPU timings of various operations.** All times returned are measured in nanoseconds.